# How to get items from DynamoDB after a specific epoch time

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, amazon-dynamodb, epoch

I have a function that accepts epoch time as date parameter. I want all the data from database after the date which is passed as a parameter.

Is there some function or an efficient way in java 8, DynamoDB through which this can be achieved?

```
public String getInfo(String fromDate, String id) {
        try {               
            Item documentItem = table.getItem(
                    new GetItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("id", id, "date", fromDate));
            if (documentItem != null) {
                LOG.info("DATA::"+documentItem.toJSONPretty());
                return documentItem.toJSONPretty();
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("errorrrr", id));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to get data from table");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html Then search on that page for `ReplyDateTime > :v_reply_dt_tm`